# Passing a list/array as request parameter in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

i'd like to know how to pass arrays as REST arguments in a GAE request. My concrete intention is to get an array of ints.

Comment: Can you be more specific? REST is using basic HTTP methods (i.e. POST, GET, etc). What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json to dump arrays and add the json string to the payload of your post.

Example:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data = {'list_1' : list_1, 'list_2' : list_22}
response = urlfetch.fetch(url='http://....', payload=simplejson.dumps(data), method=urlfetch.POST,
                          headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```